# flutter get files code not working on android 12

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I want to read and get different files like mp3, pdf , and jpg.  and working fine but on android 12 listing files not working
**here is code to get files**

```
 void getFiles() async {
if ( await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request().isGranted) {
  // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
}
//asyn function to get list of files
List<StorageInfo> storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();
var root = storageInfo[0]
    .rootDir; //storageInfo[1] for SD card, geting the root directory
var fm = FileManager(root: Directory(root)); //
files = await fm.filesTree(
    excludedPaths: ["/storage/emulated/0/ssssssssssss"],
    extensions: ["jpg"] //optional, to filter files, list only pdf files
    );

setState(() {}); //update the UI
```

}
**Error**
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/...' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

**permissions**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

<application
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: show error response

Comment: shared .tried everything from 4 days still getting error

Comment: Could you manually check storage permissions for the app on android 12 (Go to settings of the app). The permission may be permanently denied and you have to approve of the permission manually (By button).

Comment: i try this also not working